# How to write the request url if have a two path variable in Spring?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, pagination, thymeleaf

I have two pages: **`studentExam`** and **`accessedExam`**. In the **`accessedExam`** page, I have implement the pagination using the `PagedListHolder`.

In order navigate back and forth, I have add the path variable of the page number in the request url. But I failed to link this between this two pages with the button because the program always indicate that the request url is false. My question is how to write the request url if have a two path variable in Spring?

Below are the getMapping for the **`studentExam`** and **`accessedExam`**

```java
@GetMapping("/student_Exam")
    public String viewStudentHomePage(Model model, Principal principal) {
        model.addAttribute("user",new User());
        model.addAttribute("exam",new Exam());
            
        User user = userService.findUserByEmailPrincipal(principal.getName());      
        
        model.addAttribute("profile_Username", user.getUsername());
        model.addAttribute("enrolledExamList",user.getRegisteredExam());
        
        return "/student/studentExam";
    }
```

```java
@GetMapping("/exam/{id}/{pageNumber}")
public String viewExamPage(Model model, Principal principal,@PathVariable( name= "id") Long examId, @PathVariable(name="pageNumber") int pageNumber) {
}
```

The button that I used to navigate from  **`studentExam`** to **`accessedExam`** page

```html
<div class="card ms-3" style="width: 18rem;" th:each = "exam:${enrolledExamList}">                      
    <a id="exmRedirectBtn" th:href = "@{/exam/{id}/{pageNumber}(id=${exam.id})(pageNumber=${pageNumber})}" class="btn btn-primary">Access</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the docs for [standard url syntax](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html#adding-parameters) .

```
th:href="@{/exam/{id}/{pageNumber}(id=${exam.id}, pageNumber=${pageNumber})}"
```